# Longer text in an inline-block shifts alignment

Tags: html, css

Why does long text inside a inline-block shift alignment of the block *before*?

This is my code:

```css
ul.card { display: block }
li.card { 
          display: inline-block; 
          width: calc(12em - 12px); 
          height: calc(12em - 12px); 
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 6px; 
          background-color: maroon; color: white 
}
```

```html
<ul class="card">
   <li class="card test"><a href="#">Short text</a></li>
   <li class="card test">Longer text shifts alignment</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the way it shows up:

[image]

which becomes ok with short text:

[image]

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/simonecesano/pen/OJzyeKb)

Why is that? how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: inline-block` is to make your element inline with others and respect height/width, margin, and padding, but the problem with your case is you set limited width and now the line-height of your content changed to align with your text

If you remove the height, you can observe it like this

[image]

For a quick fix, you can set `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
li.card {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(12em - 12px);
  height: calc(12em - 12px);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: maroon;
  color: white
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans
}
```

```html
<ul class="card">
  <li class="card test"><a href="#">Short text</a></li>
  <li class="card test"><a href="#">Short text ok da  da das dasdas das </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.card {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a vertical aligning issue, caused by the default value. You would need `vertical-align: middle;` on `li.card`, like this:

```css
ul.card {
  display: block;
}
li.card {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(12em - 12px);
  height: calc(12em - 12px);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: maroon;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="card">
  <li class="card test"><a href="#">Short text</a></li>
  <li class="card test">Longer text shifts alignment</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```css
ul.card { display: flex }
li.card { 
          display: inline-block; 
          width: calc(12em - 12px); 
          height: calc(12em - 12px); 
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 6px; 
          background-color: maroon; color: white 
}
li.card:not(:last-child){
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="card">
   <li class="card test"><a href="#">Short text</a></li>
   <li class="card test">Longer text shifts alignment</li>
</ul>
```